# Rails Access belongs_to Fields in .Where Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I want to assign all objects meeting a certain condition to a variable. I would typically do this with a statement like:

```
pending_requests = Request.all.where(:requestee_id => current_user.id)
```

I now want to do something similar for an Exchange class, which belongs_to the Request class.

```
pending_exchanges = Exchange.all.where(? => current_user.id)
```

The ? needs to equal whatever code is necessary to compare the requestee_id field in the specific Request object that the Exchange object belongs to. There is a field request_id in the Exchange object which holds the ID of the request object it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exchange.joins(:request).where("requests.requestee_id" => current_user.id)
```

The `joins` pulls in the other table's fields in the SQL query so that you can have a where clause which refers to them. I'm assuming the name of the Request table is `requests`.